# Python/SqlAlchemy computed columns using M2Crypto

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, m2crypto

I have two foreign tables in my postgres database that are 'related' not formally connected by a 'foreign key' (for security reasons), called Account and Profile.

Account has a column called 'encrypted_UUID' and Profile has a column called 'UUID', where a row in Account can be informally associated with a row in Profile by decrypting the Account's UUID and searching for the row in Profile with the decrypted UUID.

I have successfully been able to decrypt individual UUIDs from Account using M2Crypto:

```
import hashlib
import M2Crypto.EVP

ENCRYPT = 1
DECRYPT = 0

def hash_key(key_phrase=None):
    hasher512 = hashlib.sha512()
    if key_phrase is None:  # get from vault
        key_phrase = vault_key
    hasher512.update(str(key_phrase))
    return hasher512.digest()

def crypt(data, key_phrase=None, iv=None, whichway=DECRYPT):
    key = hash_key(key_phrase)
    if iv is None:
        iv = vault_iv
    cipher = M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher(algo, key, iv, whichway)
    return cipher.update(data) + cipher.final()

def decrypt(data, key_phrase=None, iv=None):
    return crypt(data, key_phrase, iv, DECRYPT)

def encrypt(data, key_phrase=None, iv=None):
    #data = data.encode('utf-8')
    return crypt(data, key_phrase, iv, ENCRYPT)
```

where `vault_key`, `vault_iv`, and `algo` are things that I will keep secret but is used for the encryption/decryption.

So for any Account, I can say `decrypt(Account.query.all()[0].uuid)` and get the decrypted UUID string, then look for the corresponding Profile with that decrypted UUID.

Now, I am trying to do a join using SQLAlchemy for the two tables Account and Profile using the two using a computed column for decrypted UUIDs on Account.

Here's what I have for the models:

```
class Account(db.Model):
    encrypted_uuid = db.Column(db.LargeBinary())
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def decrypted_uuid(self):
        return decrypt(self.encrypted_uuid)

    @decrypted_uuid.expression
    def decrypted_uuid(cls):
        return decrypt(cls.encrypted_uuid)

class Profile(db.Model):
    uuid = db.Column(db.String())
    ...
```

and here's my attempt at the join:

```
query = db.session
            .query(Account.email, Profile.last_name, Profile.first_name)
            .join(Profile, Profile.uuid == Account.decrypted_uuid)
```

However, I get an error when I try to make the query:

```
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

where the stack can be traced back to calling `decrypt` on `cls.encrypted_uuid` in the `Account` model.

In my past experience, computed columns are gotten by almost mimicking the calculations under the hybrid_property/method definition exactly.

I have a feeling this is because I'm trying to call `decrypt` on something that is of class `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object` instead of a `str` class like the `decrypt` function expects.

Comment: Just to be sure, we are talking about ``py2k`` here, right? ``M2Crypto`` is not compatible with ``py3k`` yet.

Comment: @mcepl that's right, py2k. Thanks!